# How to send http post with json body request in chainlink?

Tags: http, post, chainlink

I have already learned how to send http get request from chainlink document, but i don't know how to send a http post request.

For example, when we want to get the block number of Kovan testnet, we can exec a curl command:

```
curl https://rinkeby-light.eth.linkpool.io/ \
    -X POST \
    -d '{"method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

and then we will get a response like this:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x919cd2"}
```

the `result` of the response is the block number.

I find a POST->Uint256 [job](https://market.link/jobs/52f6d8a8-f82b-46c1-bebc-f1d8969c207b) of Kovan testnet and then modeled on the http get sample code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";

/**
 * THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CONTRACT WHICH USES HARDCODED VALUES FOR CLARITY.
 * PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION.
 */
contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

    uint256 public blockNumber;

    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;

    /**
     * Network: Kovan
     * Oracle: 0x109391576634572AA0a18EE0BD3854Ad71Cf814d (Fibodor kovan)
     * Job ID: a100c3e583484688be229c6883a2cac3
     * Fee: 0.1 LINK
     */
    constructor() {
        setPublicChainlinkToken();
        oracle = 0x917d919dDD0faa12C71146E7DE9BdDD28A7e4aA0;
        jobId = "669d8dac695d4c44b4d65397d4bd253e";
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // (Varies by network and job)
    }
    
    /**
     * Create a Chainlink request to retrieve API response, find the target data
     */
    function requestData() public returns (bytes32 requestId)
    {
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);

        // Set the URL to perform the POST request on
        request.add("post", "https://rinkeby-light.eth.linkpool.io/");
        request.add("body", "{\"id\":0,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"eth_blockNumber\",\"params\":[]}");

        // Set the path to find the desired data in the API response, where the response format is:
        // {
        //  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        //  "id": 1,
        //  "result": "0x919cd2"
        // }
        request.add("path", "result");
        
        // no need to multiply
        request.addInt("times", 1);

        // Sends the request
        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    }

    /**
     * Receive the response in the form of uint256
     */
    function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _blockNumber) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
    {
        blockNumber = _blockNumber;
    }

    // function withdrawLink() external {} - Implement a withdraw function to avoid locking your LINK in the contract
}
```

I deployed the contract with remix to Kovan at the [address](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x79a0dD58612C8DA64BeC6B27ce22ea9eE62E8ce7) and fund it with 0.2 LINK. Everything is prepared and i call the `requestData`, [tx](https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x9e2f9e68747a05a1fa6faef3c70cc68cf73325775a0be0bc403845d888ed5347) send success, but i can't see the oracle callback and the `blockNumber` is always zero.

Please help me where is my code wrong.

Comment: Your code looks correct... it could be that the node is down. Have you checked if their node is down?

Comment: I tried some other kovan nodes but still not work, I noticed that  [httppost](https://docs.chain.link/docs/core-adapters/#httppost) document says `Headers & Body

Currently not available on-chain. Available for job specs only.` May be we can not add 'body' param in contract.

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't see you added a body. Yes. This is likely whats wrong.

Comment: @PatrickCollins  Is post request support by chainlink internal adapter or we have to make external adapter for post request?